# Naming convention for percentages

Tags: convention

I have a variable which I've named $TotalRecords$, and another variable which is a subset of $TotalRecords$ which I've named $ExistingFields$

If I calculate $(ExistingFields/TotalRecords) * 100 = x$

What are some naming conventions for the result of that ratio which can be used in place of $x$?

Comment: You would get how many *procent* are the existing ones of the whole

Comment: @Vinyl_cape_jawa Right, so how/what would you name that result(using the example variables I provided), following the naming conventions/standards?

Comment: Naming conventions are dependent on your situation, it is not a mathematical thing. And it is not something that people who don't know your situation are going to be able to help you with. `PercentageExisting` is about the best I can suggest from the little information here. Or if you don't mind really long names, `PercentageOfTotalRecordsWithExistingFields`.